# R: uso de variables dinámicas para generar código a incluir en un mutate - case_when con un parámetro string

Tags: r, r-dplyr, tidyverse

tengo una función para generar un código estátito a partir de variables dinámicas que entran como parámetro. La cuestión es que dichas variables están en una lista de `"string"`.
Por ejemplo:

```
lista_V12 = c("V121","V122", "V123", "V124")
lista_V13 = c("V131","V132", "V133", "V134", "V135")
```

Se corresponden con nombres de variables de un df/tibble. Y desde cada lista, se hace referencia a las columnas que se van a usar para generar otra nueva. Para ello, como se va a realizar con distintas agrupaciones de columnas/variables de un total de 154, quiero crear una función que automatice el proceso a partir de parámetros: df/tibble, nombre de la nueva variable, lista de variables de calculo.

```
crear_VConjunta <- function(df_datos, vble, lista_vbles) {
  bd_int = df_datos %>% select(all_of(lista_vbles))
```

Proceso: aplicar mutate sobre un case_when cuyo contenido genero así:

```
condiciones = purrr::imap(lista_vbles, ~quo(!!.x == 1 ~!!.y))
```

Aplico mutate para crear la nueva columna variable. La lista se incluye en los criterios de un case_when en su parte izquierda, es decir para indicar nombres de columna originales pero también influye la posición en la lista para asignar un código en la nueva columna/variable.

```
vfin = bd_int %>% mutate("{vble}" := case_when(!!!condiciones))
```

El problema aparece cuando en las condiciones, la lista de "string" permanece con las dobles comillas y no consigue hacer referencia a la columna específica que sí ha generado con la primera instrucción de la función:

```
bd_int = df_datos %>% select(all_of(lista_vbles))
```

Pero en el caso de la meta programación, al generar el texto estático con `purrr::imap` el contenido de la lista lo genera como `"V121"` y no como `V121`, que es lo deseable, quedando un cógido final para `mutate - case_when`:

Incorrecto: puesto que `condiciones`, aparece como un `quosure`, pero que viene a generar este contenido (no literal, pero es el efectivo al final):

```
  vfin = bd_int %>% mutate("{vble}" := case_when("V121" == 1 ~1,
                                                 "V122" == 1 ~2,
                                                 "V123" == 1 ~3,
                                                 "V124" == 1 ~4,
                                                 "V125" == 1 ~5))
```

Con esta doble comilla que viene arrastrada de la lista de str pasada como parámetro. Internamente, `condiciones`, no da error en el procesamiento, pero no encuentra dichas variables.

Correcto:

```
  vfin = bd_int %>% mutate("{vble}" := case_when(V121 == 1 ~1,
                                                 V122 == 1 ~2,
                                                 V123 == 1 ~3,
                                                 V124 == 1 ~4,
                                                 V125 == 1 ~5))
```

Sí es capaz de generar la nueva columna con los valores adecuados.

No encuentro una forma de conseguir que el contenido de `condiciones` tenga la llamada a la variable `V121` y no la cadena `"V121"`.

Para tener todo el código de la función:

```
crear_VConjunta <- function(df_datos, vble, lista_vbles) {
  bd_int = df_datos %>% select(all_of(lista_vbles))

  condiciones = purrr::imap(lista_vbles, ~quo(!!.x == 1 ~!!.y))
  vfin = bd_int %>% mutate("{vble}" := case_when(!!!condiciones))
  vfin
}
```

He intentado manipular el quosure, eliminar a mano las comillas directamente sobre el mismo, pero es una estructura interna de expresiones evaluables que no es fácil de tocar y genera otros problemas.

Los datos sobre los que opero una vez realizada la selección:
Los datos de partida son:

```
# A tibble: 60 × 5
    V121  V122  V123  V124  V125
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     0     1     0     0
 2     0     0     1     0     0
 3     0     0     1     0     0
 4     1     0     0     0     0
 5     0     0     1     0     0
 6     0     0     1     0     0
 7     0     1     0     0     0
 8     0     0     1     0     0
 9     0     1     0     0     0
10     0     0     1     0     0
# … with 50 more rows
```

Y el objetivo sería que apareciera una nueva columna `V12`, en la que se recodifique todo, pasando cada aparición de 1 en las columnas previas a un código según esto:

```
1 en V121 a 1 en V12
1 en V122 a 2 en V12
1 en V123 a 3 en V12
1 en V124 a 4 en V12
1 en V125 a 5 en V12
```

Ese es el objetivo. Como se trata de realizar esto unas 15 veces en una tabla de 154 columnas, había pensado en una solución automatizada con esta función.
Gracias, porque parece que ya está más cerca la solución.

Todo esto lo he ido haciendo consultando:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861055/how-can-i-use-mutate-and-case-when-in-a-for-loop#57861182

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/use-dynamic-name-for-new-column-variable-in-dplyr

https://www.desarrollo-web-br-bd.com/es/r/pegar-nombre-de-variable-en-mutate-dplyr/838366735/amp/

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido Fernando a SO en español. Tu pregunta es muy interesante y pertinente para este sitio y etiqueta. Podrías mejorarla (y aumentar la probabilidad de recibir una respuesta) de dos maneras: 1) con un ejemplo de los datos para hacerla reproducible, que ayudaría a reproducir el error y asegurar que la respuesta sea adecuada. 2) con una descripción del resultado que buscas obtener y un contexto del problema, ya que puede haber una aproximación diferente y quizás más eficiente para el problema.

Comment: ¿Lo que buscas es que la nueva variable te regrese, para cada fila, la posición de la primera columna que es igual a 1? Si es así `apply(bd_int, 2, \(x) x == 1) |> apply(1, which) |> sapply(min)` funciona y no dependen de `rlang`. Sería cuestión de conformar la matriz `bd_int` y envolverla la función en un `mutate()`.

Comment: Buenas tardes Martin, al respecto del primer comentario, sobre mejorar la pregunta. Quizás no me he explicado bien, en el desarrollo, pongo dos bloques de código, uno "incorrecto" y otro "correcto", donde la principal diferencia es que lo que querría conseguir es que en el "incorrecto" desapareciesen las comillas de la variable V121 a V125. Es decir, cómo referencias explícitamente una variable, desde una lista como es lo que devuelve colnames. Gracias!!

Comment: Respecto al segundo, no, no quiero las posiciones, quiero referencia una variable en el ámbito de mutate, extrayendo valores de una lista, tal como hago en la metaprogramacion de purrr::imap . Saludos

Comment: Hola Fernando, puse una respuesta que creo que soluciona el problema. Si puedes incluir unos datos de ejemplo. No tienen que ser los tuyos, quw quizás no se puedan hacer públicos, pero unos de estructura similar podría testear si en efecto funciona para el problema que intenta resolver. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que encontré una solución, aunque sigo sin entender muy bien el problema.

Puedes usar la función `rlang::syms()` para convertir a la lista de nombres de variables (especificada en la clase `character`)  a una lista de símbolos. No es que "le saca las comillas", los convierte en *defused expressions*, expresiones que R no evaluará tan pronto las vea, como lo haría normalmente si fueran nombres. Es decir, son nombres *enfriados* para que no se evalúen.

Entonces:

```
crear_VConjunta <- function(df_datos, vble, lista_vbles) {

  lista_vbles = rlang::syms(lista_vbles)  #Aquí pasa de string a símbolo: expresiones defused para que no se evalúen hasta que `eval_tidy` dentro de case_when lo pida.
  
  bd_int = df_datos %>% select(!!!lista_vbles)  #Acá uso !!! para inyectar la lista de variables
  
  condiciones = purrr::imap(lista_vbles, ~quo(!!.x == 1 ~!!.y))
  vfin = bd_int %>% mutate("{vble}" := case_when(!!!condiciones))
  vfin
}
```

Debería funcionar. No tengo datos de prueba para testear la solución.

Comment: Buenas, esto ha conseguido, creo, la sintaxis que quería. Ahora el quosure contiene una referencia a símbolos y debería funcionar. Entiendo que lo convierte a defused expressions. (eso lo había leído pero no sabía muy bien qué significaba).
Ahora el error viene en la ejecución:
"Error in local_error_context(dots = dots, .index = i, mask = mask) : 
entrada en evaluacion: recursivo por defecto o problemas anteriores?"

Comment: Quizás el problema sea con los datos de tu entorno. El test que pude hacer es `crear_VConjunta(mtcars, "algo", lista_vbles = list("am", "vs"))` y no da ese error.

Comment: Correcto, me había dejado atrás una variable. Muchas gracias!!! Ya resuelto.

Comment: Que bueno! `rlang` es una lata, es muy potente pero tiene muchos conceptos parecidos y difíciles de entender y de saber cuál es el correcto en cada momento.